# Is there any way to add just an icon to a MailChimp embed form 'submit' button?

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

I'm using a MailChimp embed form to collect email addresses for a newsletter.

My client's design uses just a right arrow instead of the word "Subscribe", however, when I try to put any other value aside from *text* in the "value" section, it outputs raw data vs font-awesome.

Is there a way to manipulate the submit button's **"value="Subscribe"** in the embedded text to use an arrow like the screenshot attached (Client design)?

```
<!-- EMAIL INPUT -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
</div>
```

**Client's design:**

[image]

**The result if I try to use Font Awesome as a value:**
[image]

I've also tried to use CSS and content"" but that didn't have any effect.

```
.tertiary_btn.et_pb_button:after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"!important;
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f178";
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 25px;
  opacity: 1!important;
  transition: none!important;
  margin-left: 8px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 4px;
  color: inherit;
}
```

I also looked into their "[fredicons](https://ux.mailchimp.com/patterns/icons)" but I am not sure if these are meant to be used with the embed forms as they too had no effect.

If you have had to use an arrow vs text within a MailChimp embed form in the past and know the best way to tackle this, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<button>` instead `<input type="submit">`

```css
button {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
width: 200px;
}

input[type="text"] {
width: 200px;
background-image: url("https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/271/271228.png");
background-position: 98%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<input type="text" placeholder="textfield">
<button>Subscribe <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```